# Looking for a Macro/VBA Code that removes alternate duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA that can help me run through a list in one column and perform the following steps:

- Identify every alternate duplicate
- Delete the alternate duplicate
- Shift the content up, getting rid of the blank cells

The sheet contains only one column.

Example:

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Strawberry
4. Apple
5. Strawberry
6. Kiwi
7. Apple
8. Apple

I would need No. 4, 5 and 8 removed.

I hope that this makes sense.

Thanks a ton :)

Comment: What have you tried to write so far? a for loop with step-1 would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1:A" & LastRow), .Range("A" & i).Value) > 1 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```